# SGE/OGS 2011 breaking Ansys Workbench Mechanical launch due to network port blocked

Tags: linux, redhat, gridengine

We are running a SGE / OGS compute cluster on EL6 and are trying to launch an interactive Ansys Workbench. This works using SSH with X Forwarding, but using qrsh fails to run the Mechanical component - Workbench itself does launch OK.

It looks like it cannot launch / connect to a high port it is trying to access on localhost. We think this may be an issue with the grid software? How can I allow high ports on loopback to be used? We're authenticating using kerberos across the entire computing infrastructure so it's using tickets to log in to interactive jobs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I follow below steps to configure workbench and other interactive jobs using qrsh.

1. create file qlogin.sh

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   HOST=$1
   PORT=$2

   if [ "x$DISPLAY" = "x" ]; then
   exec /usr/bin/ssh -p $PORT $HOST
   else
   exec /usr/bin/ssh -X -Y -p $PORT $HOST 
   fi
   ```
2. Now modify the configuration using qconf -mconf

   ```
   qlogin_command               /opt/gridengine/bin/qlogin.sh
   qlogin_daemon                /usr/sbin/sshd -i -o Protocol=2
   rlogin_command               /usr/bin/ssh
   rlogin_daemon                /usr/sbin/sshd -i -o Protocol=2
   rsh_command                  /usr/bin/ssh
   rsh_daemon                   /usr/sbin/sshd -i -o Protocol=2
   ```